# Как усреднить и уменьшить список точек для графика

Tags: python, алгоритм

Алгоритм формирует список значений в среднем от 300к до 1М точек (зависит от того достигается ли сходимость и в какой момент). Отрисовка графика по всем этим точкам занимает много времени, а при сохранении ноутбука с графиком на диск - ноутбук занимает много места.

Поэтому хотелось бы уменьшить число точек до 100. Т.е. разделить получаемый список точек на 100 сэмплов и в каждом семпле получить усреднённое значение после чего сформировать уже список из 100 полученных значений. Вопрос в том как это лучше и эффективнее сделать, есть ли эффективные алгоритмы для этого?

Comment: давайте использовать обепринятую терминологую. Ноутбук на диск сохранить нельзя, потому что диск находится внутри ноутбука.

Comment: файлы jupiter notebook вполне сохраняются на диск. Если бы мы говорили про C++ то наверное такой термин нельзя было бы использовать, в данном случае не вижу проблемы

Comment: А нужно ли вам реально это усреднение? Вы не пробовали взять скажем каждую 10 000-ю точку и построить по ним график? Да или просто взять 1000 точек из массива через `df.sample` (или где у вас точки лежат?) и нарисовать только их? Или у вас точки прям так сильно скачут?

Comment: это отлично, что файлы jupiter notebook вполне сохраняются на диск. Вот только в вопросе нет ни слова о jupiter.

Comment: ну вначале регрессии значения скачут. Я попробовал df.sample, но он выдаёт точки случайно, мне это не подходит. Точки лежат в numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так, например, с использованием `Pandas` для аггрегации. Работает моментально:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.randint(100, size=1_000_000)})
df['bin'] = df.index // 10_000
df_avg = df.groupby('bin').mean()

df_avg[['data']].plot()
```

Картинку не могу сейчас приложить, к сожалению.

А вообще в случае, если данные у вас слабо меняются со временем, то, возможно, аггрегация не нужна и достаточно сэмплирования. Попробуйте, сравните:

```py
df.sample(100)[['data']].sort_index().plot()
```

Вообще сэмплирование - очень мощная техника. Когда у вас много данных, с которыми ваше оборудование физически не справляется, бывает полезно взять какой-то сэмпл данных и экспериментировать с ним - так всё гораздо быстрее можно проверить.